# heroku[router] gets old and wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app deployed on heroku, and there is an annoying issue: my router heroku gets an url that doesn't exist anymore (I have deleted everything on my WebApp regarding the notifications). 
Do you have any idea where it could come from?

Here are what my logs :

```
2015-06-25T12:22:30.357205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/notifications" host=www.krawd.com request_id=6b03fbec-88ee-48bd-8afd-aa6d59a9bf53 fwd="82.237.217.103" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=377
2015-06-25T12:22:30.334224+00:00 app[web.3]: source=rack-timeout id=8b3b9046-8613-44fb-8274-c0dc976d3472 wait=16ms timeout=25000ms state=ready
2015-06-25T12:22:30.362821+00:00 app[web.3]: source=rack-timeout id=8b3b9046-8613-44fb-8274-c0dc976d3472 wait=16ms timeout=25000ms service=29ms state=active
2015-06-25T12:22:30.406680+00:00 app[web.3]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms
2015-06-25T12:22:30.341720+00:00 app[web.1]: source=rack-timeout id=6b03fbec-88ee-48bd-8afd-aa6d59a9bf53 wait=0ms timeout=25000ms service=0ms state=active
2015-06-25T12:22:30.344956+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/notifications"):
```

Comment: I suppose someone could be visiting that page (robot or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you search your web app folder for "/notifications" and see if you forgot some reference somewhere. Does the request happen when you run on localhost? You could trace it more easily that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It never happens on localhost, only in production and notifications are nowhere to be found in the application.

Comment: @FanaHOVA this should have been a comment.  It is a set of suggestions, not an answer to the question.